# How would I read conditional survival rates for plots?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

[image]

**I have a dataset and performed some code on it:**

```
remotes::install_github("zabore/condsurv")
library(condsurv)

fit1 <- survfit(Surv(time, DEATH_EVENT) ~ 1, data = HF)

gg_conditional_surv(
  basekm = fit1, 
  at = seq(0, 160, 80),
  main = "Conditional Survival in HF Data",
  xlab = "Days",
  ylab = "Survival Probability"
  )
```

The dataset I performed this on can be found [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Heart+failure+clinical+records).

I honestly just plotted it because I found the code and I recently taught myself survival analysis. Does someone know how I can read this plot?

I know that the green line means "probability of survival rate given patient survived 80 days" but is there more to it?

**If I happen to subset the overall dataset, I get the same graph:**
[image]

With:

```
One = HF
Two = filter(HF, time >= 80)
Three = filter(HF, time >= 160)
```

All of this makes sense. There's nothing mathematical about it, I sense. It's simply saying "***given these patients survived the last subset, they will have this new survival rate because the deceased patients aren't adding any weight to the new overall distribution***".

**Is there anymore to add?**

Comment: The second plot just looks wrong. The blue line would indicate no survival at time > 160. But then you appear to have raised some of them from the dead.

Comment: @IRTFM Thank you for this comment. It was hilarious and made me update the question after having played around with the filters

Comment: The only thing to add is that it is _both_ the deceased and those censored prior to your two conditional times that have dropped out of the risk set available for subsequent events. It is only at events that estimates are recalculated.